# IOS BLE NSData int to byte issue

Tags: ios, byte

I want to write values to BLE with `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:`, 
the value is an int value from `2000-01-01 00:00:00` to now in seconds.

```
int time_distance 468436137;

nsigned char *bytes=(unsigned char *)&time_distance;

NSData *da_sec=[NSData dataWithBytes: bytes length:sizeof(time_distance)];
```

`da_sec` is `a9c4eb1b` which is wrong, it rather should be `1bebc4a9`.

a9 c4 eb 1b => 1b eb c4 a9.

this is reversed.. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you ever heard the phrase "endian" before?  If not, then you should look into it.  This is expected behavior.

Comment: @borrrden Tut, they just don't teach *Gulliver's Travels* at school any more...

Comment: its call little endian.

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

```
 var timeInterval:Int = Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970)

 let data = NSData(bytes: &timeInterval, length: 
 MemoryLayout<Int>.size)

 let sendData:Data = (data as Data)

 self.selectPeripheral.writeValue(sendData, for: readWriteChar, type: .withResponse)
```